# Javascript date() function not working

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript so i was practicing with javascript Date() function. I have shown below. But this code not work even i have print any below variables the output is nothing (blank page). How to fix it.

```
var rightTime = new Date();

            var currentHour = rightTime.getHours();

            switch(true)
            {

            case (currentHour > 8 && currentHour < 12)
                document.write("Gud Morning");
                break;
            case (currentHour === 12)
                document.write("Gud After Noon");
                break;

            default:
                document.write("Gud Night");
                break;      
            }
```

Comment: date functions is probably fine - check your browser console for the real problem :

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `:` in each `case`

```
var rightTime = new Date();

var currentHour = rightTime.getHours();

switch(true)
{

      case (currentHour > 8 && currentHour < 12):
          document.write("Gud Morning");
          break;
      case (currentHour === 12):
          document.write("Gud After Noon");
          break;
      default:
          document.write("Gud Night");
          break;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
switch(true) {

    case (currentHour > 8 && currentHour < 12)
        document.write("Gud Morning");
        break;
    case (currentHour == 12)
        document.write("Gud After Noon");
        break;

    default:
        document.write("Gud Night");
        break;      
    }
```

You could write:

```
if(currentHour > 8 && currentHour < 12)  {
    document.write("Gud Morning");
} else if(currentHour === 12) {
    document.write("Gud After Noon");
} else {
    document.write("Gud Night");
}
```

Comment: Completely rewriting it doesn't explain what's wrong with the OP's code.

Comment: @nnnnnn True, but why would you use a switch like this?

Comment: I wouldn't. (Except in exceptional circumstances: I vaguely remember finding the `switch(true)` "trick" handy for some specific thing I was coding long enough ago that I forget what it was, but being able to make use of some fall-through cases helped at the time.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Agree again. I wanted to emphasize this special case, when I guess it is not better to use a switch... Of course I get your point, but this not a cse like that... :)